# Why does my while loop break at end even when I make sure my game_start variable is still 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I've tried adding breaks and continues in multiple formats such as if/else structures and also just adding the break and continues right after and no matter how I structured it nothing worked. I'm not getting an error code but it is breaking out of the while loop even if x is inputted as 0 in the continue check.
The Basic set up of the code is:

```
import random
x = 0
while x == 0:
  guess = int(input(stuff))
    while ((guess > 9) or (guess < 0))
      guess = int(input('invalid response')
  num = random.randint(0,9)
  if guess == num:
    print('correct')
    x = int(input('continue? yes = 0, no = 1')
  else:
    print('incorrect')
    x = int(input('continue? yes = 0, no = 1')
```

I originally tried to have a check outside of the else if statement set as:

```
while (x != 0) or (x != 1):
  x = int(input('\nNon-valid response please pick 0 for yes or 1 for no.'))
```

but I kept getting an invalid syntax error.

Comment: You might want to provide your real code, because the code you presented has some errors (missing colon and closing parentheses; screwed up indentation for the while), but after fixing that, everything is correct. The loop is exited if you enter `0`.

Comment: Additionally: Do you really want to create a new random number in the loop? The way you wrote it, the number to guess will most likely change after you give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok mate, you've got *a lot* of syntax errors, particularly when it comes to not closing your brackets (an open bracket ALWAYS needs a closing bracket), so if x number of open brackets, you need an x number of closing brackets.

If you're using VSCode (Visual Studio Code), then I recommend an extension called "Rainbow Brackets", but it should already be integrated to VSCode (the extension is decprecated). The first bracket's colour has to match the last bracket's colour, like [image: Good Syntax], not [image: Bad Syntax].

Try the code below:

```py
import random
x = 0
while x == 0:
    guess = int(input('Input guess >> '))
    while ((guess > 9) or (guess < 0)):
        guess = int(input('invalid response'))
    num=random.randint(0, 9)
    if guess == num:
        print('correct')
        x=int(input('continue? yes = 0, no = 1 > '))
    else:
        print('incorrect')
        x=int(input('continue? yes = 0, no = 1 > '))
```

Comment: For the loop I prefer `while not 0 <= guess <= 9:`, but that's opinion-based.

Comment: I guess, but the way Edalyn has written the `input` statements wouldn't make it work. Maybe if no = 1 and yes = 0 was swapped to yes=1 and no=0? But then still, 2-9 would still register as yes. You do make a valid point though.

Comment: My presented way for the comparison doesn't change the outcome. It just looks different.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
import random
x = 0
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Input guess"))
        if not (0 <= guess <= 9):
            print("Guess not between 0 and 9")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("Guess is not a Number")
        continue
    num = random.randint(0,9)
    if guess == num:
        print('correct')
        x = int(input('continue? yes = 0, no = 1'))
    else:
        print('incorrect')
        x = int(input('continue? yes = 0, no = 1'))
    if x == 1:
        break
```